# DBMS_RUNJAVA doesn't find my class

Tags: java, oracle, loadjava

I would like to run a java program on my oracle server `12C`.
I tried that but it's not working :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "HELLO" AS
public class Hello {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("succeed");
      }
}
;

SELECT dbms_java.runjava('-cp jserver:/CP/SHARED_DATA/PRIVATE/SCHEMA/LLAMARCHE/ Hello')  FROM DUAL;
```

This returns :

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello
```

Thanks......

Comment: 'Hello' and 'HELLO' are not the same thing.

Comment: If I change HELLO by Hello it gives the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this by other way:

First, create the java class.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Hello" AS
import java.io.*;
public class Hello {
public static void executeCommand() {
    System.out.println("succeed");
}
};
/
```

Later, create an oracle procedure that invoke this class, like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CallHello
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Hello.executeCommand ()';
```

And finally, make the call from the editor.

```
begin
CallHello;
end;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that works thank you. I use it waiting for the normal solution.